# Bluetooth 5.2 LE Hearing Aids CROS/Bi-CROS functionality

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I would like to realize an Android App to use with Android 5.2 Hearing Aids Buds, able to stream sound from one ear (microphone on left hearing aid) to the left ear (hearing aid on the right ear); it's like a forward of a Bluetooth mic to a Bluetooth speaker through the Android App, someone knows where I can find a useful example to do this kind of application? In the hearing aids field this feature it's called Cross (Bi-Cross if there is also an amplification in the worst ear). Thanks in advance if someone will reply to me.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CROS_hearing_aid

Comment: Do the hearing aids buds support such a feature? This can't be done without direct access to the individual input and output channels.